# Excel Export not working in IE only working in chrome (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, excel

hi all i am using `javascript` to export html table content into excel export functionality here i attached my fiddle excel export it's only working in chrome i need to working in IE also help how to solve this issues

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ode5d340/)